# Questions about 2 PCs sharing a router and viruses/malware

Tags: router

I have two Windows 8 PCs which both use the same wireless router for internet access.  I have two questions:

1) Is it possible for a virus or malware on one computer to spread to the other computer just if the two computers are using the same router?

2) It is possible for a virus or malware on one computer to send a file to the other computer?  The two computers are not connected in any way other than that they use the same router for internet access.

Comment: Most malware and viruses do not crawl to another pc on the network, older viruses that were categorized as "worms" did, but most of those network vulnerabilities if not All have been closed, that is why no one writes worms anymore. I have not seen this type of nasty in many years.

Comment: You say most don't, so it sounds possible that somebody might have come up with a way.

Comment: Like I said, I have not seen it in many years, there are too many other target rich vulnerabilities and most if not a All the worm vulnerabilities have been coded out of router firmware and OS's. Malicious websites and Phishing email's are the most common method of installing malware these days. You are safe.